# Assigning unique value ID to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**OBJECTIVE**

I am looking to extend CodeSchool's "Shaping up with Angular" tutorial. My goal is to have a user click a thumbnail which re-renders the current product image. Product images are held within a JSON file - each product has an array of multiple images.

**DEMO**

http://plnkr.co/edit/l6zqpnpTaCghjOi5zt9b?p=preview

---

**product.js**

```
app.directive("productGallery", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "product-gallery.html",
    controller: function() {
      this.current = 0;
      this.setCurrent = function(imageNumber){
        this.current = imageNumber || 0;
      };
    },
    controllerAs: "gallery"
  };
});
```

**product-gallery.html**

```
<div ng-show="product.images.length">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img ng-src="{{product.images[gallery.current]}}" />
  </div>
  <ul class="img-thumbnails clearfix">
    <li class="small-image pull-left thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in product.images">
      <img ng-click="gallery.setCurrent({{$index}})" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**ISSUE / QUESTIONS**

I am able to assign a value to each image by using $index and checking their position in the array. I want to set this value equal to the "imageNumber" which, according to product.js will change the current, main image.

1. How do I pass $index to imageNumber?
2. Is my thought process and evaluation of the problem correct?

**NOTES**

I am a programming newbie so apologies for any obvious errors - explanations are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-click` should not use `{{}}` interpolation directive.

```
<img ng-click="gallery.setCurrent($index)" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
```

> ng-click directive required Expression to evaluate upon click. (Event object is available as $event) but interpolation is not allowed it, because you have access to the scope by directly mentioning its name.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/l6zqpnpTaCghjOi5zt9b?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you - I knew something looked funky! Marked solution as resolved.

Comment: Already tried upvoting but SO requires that I have 15 reputation before upvoting :(

EDIT: I now have enough reputation to upvote - FEEL THE POWER OF +1 !!

Thanks again :)

Comment: @downvoter could I know reason behind downvote? whats wrong with mine answer?

Answer (score 0):

change `gallery.setCurrent({{$index}})` to `gallery.setCurrent($index)`.
directives like ng-click are expecting to get a javascript code, but you are using the angular templating delimiters '{{' '}}'

Comment: Ahhh..then thats ok..I added answer exact 4 minutes ago..could you take a look at answer time..